# MongoDB Combining Collections

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 simple collections "Books" and "More Info"

Books has the documents "Ref", "Title", "Author"
More Info has the documents "Ref", "No Pages", "ISBN"

The Ref field is common between both collections

I'd like to step through my main collection "Books" and for each entry check if there is any corresponding data in "More Info" and if there is, add that data as new documents into the main Books record.  Ultimately ending up with a more comprehensive Books collection.

I'm looking to do this via the Mongo Shell and assuming this can be achieved with a find().foreach function.

Any help very gratefully received.

Comment: Use aggregation pipeline, $lookup and $merge.

Comment: Thanks .... so $lookup won't interfere with find cursor (hope that make sense).

Comment: Right..........